# How to build a Swift program as a static executable?

Tags: swift, static-linking, swift-package-manager

I do not have any familiarity with the Swift Package Manager, but I have to compile a Swift program (https://github.com/ltentrup/SafetySynth, if it matters) as a statically linked executable (on Linux).

First of all. Is it possible?

The project uses the Swift Package Manager to build the executable, through the `swift build` command.

Is there any command line flags to tell the SPM to make a static executable?

This question specifically concerns the Swift Package Manager, because I'm on Linux, so I'm not using Xcode (and the project does not use Xcode neither).

Comment: swift build has an option called `--static-swift-stdlib`, but it doesn't work anymore